Should we do convergence testing on energy points in the non-equilibrium contours?
I met the following warnings after Transiesta calculations.
Begin: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS
********************************************************  
Without losing performance you can increase the non-equilibrium integration precision. 
You can add 4 more energy points in the non-equilibrium contours, for FREE! 
You are initializing the electrode EDM. This may result in erroneous forces on electrode atoms. Do not use forces from electrodes.
******************************************************** 
End: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS 

and
Begin: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS
********************************************************  
Without losing performance you can increase the non-equilibrium integration precision. 
You can add 14 more energy points in the non-equilibrium contours, for FREE! 
You are initializing the electrode EDM. This may result in erroneous forces on electrode atoms. Do not use forces from electrodes.
******************************************************** 
End: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS

These two warnings appear alternately as the bias voltage increases.
Should we do convergence testing on energy points in the non-equilibrium contours as what we do for energy vs k-points?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
